# How to run a script at the end of RStudio initialization?

Tags: r, configuration, rstudio

I want to use my browser instead of the viewer integrated in RStudio.

In order to do that one can do:

```
options(viewer = NULL)
```

I have added this line inside my `.Rprofile` file but this option seems to be modified by RStudio after reading the profile script.

Is there a way to automatically run a script after the complete initialization of RStudio?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function called .first which is automatically run when R starts. Maybe that will help. See
?Startup